# Using a Comparator to sort an ArrayList of type Student, with selection sort (cannot use Collections.sort method in this case)

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator, selection-sort

I am very stuck with this concept, and cannot seem to get my head around it. I have an assignment for school where I need to make an `ArrayList<Student>` with a value for `String name`, `String address`, and `int rollno`.

Creating the ArrayList and populating it is not the issue at all. The problem for me is having to use two Comparator classes, and a selection sort to sort the ArrayList by name, and by rollno. I cannot use the `Collections.sort` method in this case.

I am very stuck here, and would really appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Sort.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Sort {

    public Comparator<Student>sortByRoll;
    public Comparator<Student>sortByName;

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        // Declare ArrayList Student

        ArrayList<Student>studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

        // Create Objects using Student Class

        Student s1 = new Student("John Smith", 1001, "101 Meadow Ave");
        Student s2 = new Student("William James", 2011, "1201 Joney Ave");
        Student s3 = new Student("Rocky Ferguson", 3003, "1011 Bleeker Street");
        Student s4 = new Student("Kitty Roberts", 9284, "906 Dog Ave");
        Student s5 = new Student("Lionel Doe", 2100, "221 Colorado Ave");
        Student s6 = new Student("Linus Jim", 5993, "26 Cass Ave");
        Student s7 = new Student("Haley Henry", 9019, "20001 Log Blvd");
        Student s8 = new Student("Penny Cone", 1009, "11 Cracked Court");
        Student s9 = new Student("John Shepherd", 1029, "2010 Gold Street");
        Student s10 = new Student("Joshua Old", 8463, "77 Railroad Street");

        // Adding Objects to ArrayList studentList

        studentList.add(s1);
        studentList.add(s2);
        studentList.add(s3);
        studentList.add(s4);
        studentList.add(s5);
        studentList.add(s6);
        studentList.add(s7);
        studentList.add(s8);
        studentList.add(s9);
        studentList.add(s10);

    }


}
```

Student.java

```
public class Student extends Sort {

    // Variables for this class

    public int rollno;
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public String student;

    // Constructor for creating a student

    Student(String name, int rollno, String address) {

        this.name = name;
        this.rollno = rollno;
        this.address = address;

    }

    //Getters for name, address, and number

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public int getRollNo() {
        return rollno;
    }
}
```

SortByName.java

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class sortByName extends Sort implements Comparator<Student>{

        @Override
        public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {

            // Help Plz

    };
```

sortByNum.java

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class sortByNum extends Sort implements Comparator<Student> {


        @Override
        public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {

            //Help plz
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: Why does `Student` extend `Sort`? Isn't `Sort` your main application class?

Comment: @Jason yes that shouldn't be like that. I think I threw that in there as I was messing around with the program. Any tips on how I may accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to use `Collections.sort(Comparator)` because, as you stated, your assignment is to implement selection sort. I will not go into detail on the algorithm (I suppose this is your exercise), but you can implement the `compare` methods in your comparators as follows:

For roll number:

```
@Override
public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
    return Integer.compare(o1.getRollNo(), o2.getRollNo());
}
```

For name:

```
@Override
public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
    return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
}
```

Having these comparators, you can call this `compare(Student, Student)` method to get whether one student is less than (-1), equal to (0) or more than (1) the other student according to the comparator. This is what you'll be using to compare Student objects in your selection sort algorithm.

Edit on request: The sort methods themselves can be put in your main class `Sort` as follows:

```
public void sortOnRollNo(List<Student> list) {
    // Sort the list here using the sortByRoll Comparator.
}
public void sortOnStudentName(List<Student> list) {
    // Sort the list here using the sortByName Comparator.
}
```

Comment: this is very helpful, and is clearing things up. would you mind pushing me in the right direction a bit more? would it be best to create a new class for the selection sort? i dont think I'll have to big an issue once i get the whole picture together. @Pieter12345

Comment: Since there is no code formatting in comments, I've added an extra section to the answer. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

For either of your `compare` methods, you just need to return 0 if the two objects are equivalent in sort order, -1 if `o1` is 'before' `o2` in sort order, or 1 if `o1` is 'after' `o2` in sort order.

If you were comparing purely on name, you could do this:

```
@Override
public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
    return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
}
```

This uses the built in comparison for Strings.

Or if you wanted to compare based on roll number:

```
@Override
public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
    if (o1.getRollNo() == o2.getRollNo()) {
        return 0;
    } else if (o1.getRollNo() < o2.getRollNo()) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**I realise that there are more efficient ways of doing this, but I'm trying to make it clear as to what's happening.**

All you have to do, is decide which of the two students should come first, and return -1 if it's `o1`, 1 if its `o2` or 0 if they are equivalent for sort order.

Comment: would it best to put the selection sort in its own class? and how do I call the comparators in that situation?